# Javascript string functions?

Tags: javascript

I have strings like this:

```
abcdefg
abcde
abc
jjjj
```

I need is them trucated to show like this if more than a specified lenght:

```
abc ..
abc ..
abc
jjj ..
```

Is there any simple javascript code I can use for this functionality

Comment: didn't you just ask this... like 1 hr ago? except for c#?

Comment: yeah my boss now ask for javascript. It's not my fault :-(  Maybe you have a good boss but not me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function truncate(str, len) {
    if(str.length > len) {
        return str.substring(0, len) + ' ..';
    } else {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `length` property will tell you how many characters you have, and the [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) method will let you extract the first three (if there are more than you want), you can then concatenate `" .."` with the `+` operator (although `"…"` would be the usual choice).

Answer (score 0):

Well, without knowing if you have access to Array.each and some of the more recent additions:

```
// if you have them all in an array, loop through the array/
for( var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++ )
   // substr( ind, len ) = return a substring 
   //                      beginning at index ind and of len length
   strs[ i ] = strs[ i ].substr( 0, 3 );
```

Now, if you *don't* have them all in an array, then things become a good deal harder. How are you currently storing them?

Answer (score 0):

I think the substring function would be helpful. If you can get the length of a string, use substring to truncate and concatenate ".." as necessary, this is easy. You could make it a function and encapsulate everything. Would you like help with the code?

Answer (score 0):

All string will have a length property you can use to check length, but I would just pull a [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp):

```
var str = 'abcdefg';
var shortened = str.substr(0,3);
```

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-substr/ for details
else a simple code will do

```
var mystring = "aaaaaaaaaa";
var max_length = 3; //max length
mystring = mystring.substr(0, max_length);
mystring = mystring + '..'
```